# Need help installing java jre

Tags: java, jre

I need help installing java **NOT THE DEVELOPER VERSION** I can only find about the jdk here. Help? Is there easy installers anywhere?

Comment: What did you find? The metapackage `default-jre` will make sure you'll have a JRE. (OpenJDK JRE by default, not Sun!)

Comment: I meant I only found help for jdk.

Comment: @tonkku107 I don't understand your question then. What kind of help do you need? I'm assuming you know how to install packages in Ubuntu...

Comment: yes, I followed the instructions at the website but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the `default-jre` package:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Or use your favourite package manager (Synaptic, Ubuntu Software Centre, Aptitude, etc.)